# WebService Error Calling a Webservice from VBA using SOAP

Tags: xml, excel, soap, vba

I receive a web service error when attempting to execute a web service call using SOAP via VBA. The XML output and VBA code is below. I would appreciate it if anyone could advise if there is anything obviously incorrect in the VBA code.

**XML**

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"        xmlns:prag="http://www.pragmaticsw.com/">
<soap:Body>
  <prag:Bugs_LoadByCriteria>
     <prag:AuthenticationData>
        <prag:AppCode>agSP</prag:AppCode>
        <prag:DeptId>81842</prag:DeptId>
        <prag:ProjId>92553</prag:ProjId>
        <prag:UserId>147280</prag:UserId>
        <prag:PassCode>Password1</prag:PassCode>
     </prag:AuthenticationData>
     <prag:Condition><![CDATA[<Conditions     xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'
xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' Operation='opLIKE'>
<Items Type='tField'> 
  <Value xsi:type='xsd:string'>Custom17</Value> 
</Items> 
<Items Type='tString'> 
  <Value xsi:type='xsd:string'>SIT5</Value> 
</Items> 
</Conditions>]]></prag:Condition>
  </prag:Bugs_LoadByCriteria>
 </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

**VBA:**

```
Sub login()

Dim responseText As String
Dim sURL As String
Dim sEnv As String
Dim xmlhtp As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP
Dim xmlDoc As New DOMDocument
Dim webserviceSOAPActionNameSpace

sURL = "http://soap.qacomplete.smartbear.com/psWS.asmx"

sEnv = "<?xml version =""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>"
sEnv = sEnv & "<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=""http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-    envelope"" xmlns:prag=""http://www.pragmaticsw.com/"">"
sEnv = sEnv & "<soap:Body>"
sEnv = sEnv & "<prag:Bugs_LoadByCriteria>"
sEnv = sEnv & "<prag:AuthenticationData>"
sEnv = sEnv & "<prag:AppCode>agSP</prag:AppCode>"
sEnv = sEnv & "<prag:DeptId>81842</prag:DeptId>"
sEnv = sEnv & "<prag:ProjId>92553</prag:ProjId>"
sEnv = sEnv & "<prag:UserId>147280</prag:UserId>"
sEnv = sEnv & "<prag:PassCode>Password1</prag:PassCode>"
sEnv = sEnv & "</prag:AuthenticationData>"
sEnv = sEnv & "<prag:Condition><![CDATA[<Conditions     xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'"
sEnv = sEnv & "xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'    Operation='opLIKE'>"
sEnv = sEnv & "<Items Type='tField'>"
sEnv = sEnv & "<Value xsi:type='xsd:string'>Custom17</Value>"
sEnv = sEnv & "</Items>"
sEnv = sEnv & "<Items Type='tString'>"
sEnv = sEnv & "<Value xsi:type='xsd:string'>SIT4</Value>"
sEnv = sEnv & "</Items>"
sEnv = sEnv & "</Conditions>]]></prag:Condition>"
sEnv = sEnv & "</prag:Bugs_LoadByCriteria>"
sEnv = sEnv & "</soap:Body>"
sEnv = sEnv & "</soap:Envelope>"

With xmlhtp

webserviceSOAPActionNameSpace = "http://www.pragmaticsw.com/"

    .Open "POST", sURL, False

    .setRequestHeader "post", "http://soap.qacomplete.smartbear.com/psWS.asmx HTTP/1.1"
    .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/soap+xml; charset=UTF-8"
    .setRequestHeader "SOAPAction", webserviceSOAPActionNameSpace & "Bugs_LoadByCriteria"

    .send sEnv
    xmlDoc.LoadXML .responseText
    MsgBox .responseText

End With
```

End Sub

Comment: Did you test your web service with a tool like SoapUI? Start there

Comment: Thanks David. The XML was created and tested using SOAP UI. Now I am  trying to structure the XML into a format VBA can read (reference set to Microsoft XML 6.0)

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Response text below:



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><soap:Fault><soap:Code><soap:Value>soap:Receiver</soap:Value></soap:Code><soap:Reason><soap:Text xml:lang="en">Error</soap:Text></soap:Reason><soap:Node>InternalException</soap:Node><detail><Description Text="Internal WebService Error. Please contact system administrator." /></detail></soap:Fault></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>

Comment: Hi - any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Answered my own query. I sent the sEnv contents to the web service via SoapUI and received the same internal web service error. Double-checked the resulting xml data format step by step and found an additional space where there should not have been.